# D3 replaces objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Got two functions:

```
 function drawWindows(windows, scale, svg){
        let myGroups = svg.selectAll('g').data(windows);
        let myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g");
        myGroupsEnter.append("polygon")
            .style("fill", "green")
            ...
            });
  }



function drawDoors(doors, scale, svg){
            let myGroups = svg.selectAll('g').data(doors);
            let myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g");
            myGroupsEnter.append("polygon")
                .style("fill", "red")
                ...
                });
      }
```

Then a main draw function:

```
function draw(){

        var svg = d3.select('#test').append('svg');
        var scale = ...
        var doors = [...]
        var windows = [...]
        drawWindows(..);
        drawDoors(..)
}
```

Problem is, the windows replaces the doors. And vice versa if I change order. How do I keep two separate functions and still draw both?

Comment: If you don't have an update selection, try `let myGroups = svg.selectAll(null).etc...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding a class to the door and window selection,
something like below:

```
 function drawWindows(windows, scale, svg){
        let myGroups = svg.selectAll('.window').data(windows);//select all with class window
        let myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g").classed("window", true);
        myGroupsEnter.append("polygon")
            .style("fill", "green")
            ...
            });
  }



function drawDoors(doors, scale, svg){
            let myGroups = svg.selectAll('.door').data(doors);//select all with class door
            let myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g").classed('door', true);
            myGroupsEnter.append("polygon")
                .style("fill", "red")
                ...
                });
      }
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be a class. It can be anything. Or even nothing: `svg.selectAll()`.

Comment: yep `selectAll(null)` is better option. But in case you need the window selection somewhere else. Then i think it is better to have a class associated to the group.

Comment: `selectAll(null)` is way faster, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147231/selecting-null-what-is-the-reason-of-using-selectallnull-in-d3-js. The problem is that I've seen hundreds of answers suggesting the use of a class, and they don't explain to the OP the most important principle of it: you have to select **something that doesn't exist**. And `null`, `undefined`, `crazyTagTotalyFake` or just the parenthesis will all work.

Comment: Regarding the *"in case you need the window selection somewhere else"*, that's why I told OP in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47033349/d3-replaces-objects/47033663?noredirect=1#comment81013551_47033349): "*if you don't have an update selection*"

Comment: you cover up everything so well... you hold a great potential to be a great teacher...hail Aristotle :)