# How to create a line in d3js from an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to draw horizontal lines in a `d3.js` chart.

Using the below code I was able to draw lines.

```
g.append("line")
        .attr("x1", x(0.5))  
        .attr("y1", y(1))
        .attr("x2", x(3.5))
        .attr("y2", y(1))
        .style("stroke-width", 5)
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("fill", "none");
```

[image]

But I need to draw around 8 lines in the chart.

Currently I have copy pasted the above code 8 times and entered the values manually.

Is there a way to pass the coordinates from an array, instead of copy pasting it 8?

I tried to do something like this but it did not work.

method 1:

```
var dataTest = [{x1:4,y1:3,x2:6,y2:3}]

g.append("g")
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(dataTest)
    .enter()
    .append('g').attr('class', 'line').append('g')
    .attr({'x1':function(d,i){ console.log(d); return d.x1; },
                             'y1':function(d){ return d.y1; },
                             'x2':function(d,i){ return d.x2; },
                             'y2':function(d){ return d.y2; },
                        })
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .style("fill", "none");
```

method 2:

```
g.append("line")
            .attr("d", line(dataTest))
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .style("stroke", "green")
            .style("fill", "none");
```

where the line function returned the x and y values.

```
var dataTest = [{x:4,y:3},{x:6,y:3}]

var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                console.log(d.x);
                return (d.x);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return (d.y);
            });
```

Comment: In your method 1, you are creating only `g` element, did you try to create `line` elements instead of `g`?

Comment: For creating a line you have to append a `<line>`: https://jsfiddle.net/20m1x5vv/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Your solution worked for me, Thanks a lot. I would like to know why we are doing `selectAll(null)` and not `selectAll("line")` or something like that. Am just trying to understand d3js

Comment: Please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147231/selecting-null-what-is-the-reason-of-using-selectallnull-in-d3-js

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you, Can you pls look into this question and share your thoughts whether it is possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708853/how-to-change-color-of-line-functionally-in-d3js

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but unfortunately it's a lot of work for a S.O. answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you, can you point in a direction on where to and how to start?

Comment: You'll have to create different elements for different colours. A lot of math and work.

Comment: You need to understand how data binding and selection works in d3 https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/