# Adding axes eats up my data

Tags: d3.js

I'm following the D3 tutorial but adding the axis makes half of my data disappear and I don't understand why. I thought that maybe the axis is taking up the space that's meant for the data so I added an extra 10px to the transform property, but it doesn't make any difference.

```
var GIST = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/charisseysabel/f8f48fbf11b8a1b0d62cbe2d6bdc2aa6/raw/2ead1537adb822fbd59a666afd5334d525480a13/nano-2017.tsv"

var width = 1000,
height = 550,
margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 4};

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([height, 0]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(10, 0)")
    .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 540)")
    .call(yAxis);

d3.tsv(GIST, type, function(error, data) {
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  var barWidth = width / data.length;

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(" + ((i * barWidth) + 10) + ",0)"; }
    );

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", (barWidth / 2) - 2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this...

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g").etc...
```

... you're selecting group elements that already exist in the SVG, which are the axes, and binding your data to them.

There are two easy solutions:

1. Move your code that creates the axes to the bottom of the `d3.tsv`, that is, **after** you have appended the bars.
2. Select something that doesn't exist, like 
   `var bar = chart.selectAll(null).etc`. To read more about the logic behind `selectAll(null)`, have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908).

Comment: Example gist showing Gerardo's 2 recommendations in action: http://blockbuilder.org/hydrosquall/a5745c86423ccee34dcb4fda2243db03. Moving the axes code to the bottom alone didn't do it for me, but combining both of the recommendations above worked.

Comment: Sorry, when I said *"the bottom of the script"* I actually meant the bottom of the `d3.tsv`, which is **asynchronous**. If some code is at the bottom of the snippet but outside `d3.tsv`, it will be executed **before** the code inside `d3.tsv`. Have a look here, the first recommendation works alone: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d69a42346caa66d5eb77ce3ef3a29167/34863c43b6444456b279b21c84ec88581bf09f84. I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.