# d3.js binding data array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, graph, data-binding

This should be a multilinegraph
i have an array like this as data:

```
data = [[point:{x: 0, y: 1},point:{x: 0, y: 3}], [point:{x: 3, y: 1},point:{x: 3, y: 3}], [point:{x: 0, y: 6},point:{x: 1, y: 9}], [point:{x: 2, y: 6},point:{x: 3, y: 2}]]
```

code:

```
   gr.line = d3.line()
        .x((d) => d.point.x)
        .y((d) => d.point.y)
    let allGroup = gr.g.selectAll(".pathGroup").data(data)
    allGroup.exit().remove()
    let g = allGroup.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "pathGroup")


    g.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("stroke", (d) => {
            return 'red'
        })
        .attr("d", (d) => gr.line(d))
```

I want to add circles to the path. If i want to append circles to the group (in this case the variable g), i get the whole array. But i just need each item from the array to append the circle. I want to do it with data binding because i want to remove the items if the data changes. I get it done with forEach loop but i think is not a good solution. Somebody has an idea how to get it done with data binding?

Comment: Please share your line generator and tell us where do you want to append the circle (the first or the second point). Also, just for your information, `.attr("d", (d) => gr.line(d))` is the same of `.attr("d", gr.line)`.

Comment: i added line generator. I want to add circles at each point. The circles should be in the same group like the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is not valid. Judging by your line generator, you should have an array of objects, like this:

```
var data = [[{point:{x: 10, y: 10}}, {point:{x: 100, y: 30}}], 
    [{point:{x: 30, y: 100}},{point:{x: 230, y: 30}}]
];
```

Back to the question: you're correct, doing any kind of loop (as `forEach`) to append elements in a D3 code is normally a bad idea.

Just use the individual datum of the outer selection (which is an array itself)  in the inner selection:

```
g.selectAll(null)
    .data(d=>d)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    //etc...
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm using [`selectAll(null)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908) here because the enter/update/exit selections seem to operate in the outer selection, not in the inner selection. If that's not correct change that line accordingly.

Here is a demo, I'm changing the data values to better see the paths and the circles:

```js
var data = [
  [{
    point: {
      x: 10,
      y: 10
    }
  }, {
    point: {
      x: 100,
      y: 30
    }
  }],
  [{
    point: {
      x: 30,
      y: 100
    }
  }, {
    point: {
      x: 230,
      y: 30
    }
  }]
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var line = d3.line()
  .x((d) => d.point.x)
  .y((d) => d.point.y);

var allGroup = svg.selectAll(".pathGroup").data(data);

var g = allGroup.enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "pathGroup")

g.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
  .attr("d", line);

g.selectAll(null)
  .data(d => d)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .attr("cx", d => d.point.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.point.y);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: thank you this works :) I want to have the exit().remove() for the inner and outer selection. Is this possible?

Comment: i have problem to update the lines after call the function multiple times. if i call g.selectAll('path').attr("d", line) it does not work.

Comment: @KTWorks please post a *new* question, with all the relevant details.

Comment: ok thank you very much. Here is my new Question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820455/d3-update-paths-and-circles-in-graph

Comment: @Gerado Furtado maybe i you have time. Can you look on my question?