# d3 update paths and circles in Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

i want to update the graph but it does not work. I want to update the line and the circles. I tried to add

```
.exit().remove()
```

to update the circle and

```
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", line);
```

to update the paths.

However it does not work.

Updating the outside group with exit().remove() works fine. (Checkbox in this example).

Updating only the path and circle does not work. (Update Button in this example)

I dont want to remove all lines in the graph and append it again, because i want to add transition when data changes.

Here is a JS Fiddle: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/3uebkmz5/75/)
Here is my code:

```
var data = [
  [{
    point: {
      x: 10,
      y: 10
    }
  }, {
    point: {
      x: 100,
      y: 30
    }
  }],
  [{
      point: {
        x: 30,
        y: 100
      }
    }, {
      point: {
        x: 230,
        y: 30
      }
    },
    {
      point: {
        x: 50,
        y: 200
      }
    },
    {
      point: {
        x: 50,
        y: 300
      }
    },
  ]
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var line = d3.line()
  .x((d) => d.point.x)
  .y((d) => d.point.y);

function updateGraph() {
  console.log(data)
  var allGroup = svg.selectAll(".pathGroup").data(data);
  var g = allGroup.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "pathGroup")
  allGroup.exit().remove()

  g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .attr("d", line);

  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", line);

  g.selectAll(null)
    .data(d => d)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("cx", d => d.point.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.point.y)
    .exit().remove()

}
updateGraph()

document.getElementById('update').onclick = function(e) {

  data = [
    [{
      point: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10
      }
    }, {
      point: {
        x: 100,
        y: 30
      }
    }],
    [{
        point: {
          x: 30,
          y: 100
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 230,
          y: 30
        }
      },
      {
        point: {
          x: 50,
          y: 300
        }
      },
    ]
  ];
  updateGraph()
}


$('#cb1').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    data = [
      [{
        point: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 100,
          y: 30
        }
      }],
      [{
          point: {
            x: 30,
            y: 100
          }
        }, {
          point: {
            x: 230,
            y: 30
          }
        },
        {
          point: {
            x: 50,
            y: 200
          }
        },
        {
          point: {
            x: 50,
            y: 300
          }
        },
      ]
    ];

  } else {
    data = [
      [{
        point: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 100,
          y: 30
        }
      }]
    ];
  }
  updateGraph()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The reason why `allGroup.exit().remove()` does nothing is that the updated dataset still has the same number of items as the original one. The exit selection is therefore empty.

The variable `data` contains lines, not points. The one defined at page load, and the one inside `update` listener contain two lines, only the number of points in them differs.

You can check this by putting a `console.log(data.length)` inside function `updateGraph`.

### Solution 1

Change your data structure. You can assign an `id` property to each line, and use `.data`'s, `key` function. cf. [d3-selection documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data).

Updated jsFiddle implementing solution 1: [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/3uebkmz5/90/).

This solution requires less changes.

### Solution 2

In case you have no control over the data structure, you can transition the line drawing inside the `update` selection, rather than the `exit` one.

Comment: id dont understand why i have to use p3 for the id? When i want to update. So everytime i update i need a new id?

Comment: why does it work if i return undefined. Like in this js Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3uebkmz5/129/

Comment: Yes, ids must be different so that the removed lines get in the `exit` selection. If the same Id is used, then the line gets in the `update` selection. cf. documentation linked and tutorials online

Comment: It works because d3-selection's logic let this happen, for some reason. It is safer to define actual distinct keys. You can generate them based on the items' position in the array.