# D3.js not rendered properly on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm following some tutorials on D3 and just found out that Mozilla Firefox is not rendering all the `<div>` elements in my code.

Any idea on what is happening there?

```js
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("bar", true)
    .style("height", function(d){
        return d * 5  + "px";
    });
```

```css
div.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 75px; /* We'll override height later */
  background-color: teal;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Chrome (correct)
[image]

Firefox (just 4 divs are displayed)
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour (Firefox 59, Mac OS). Try selecting null (https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908) and tell us what happens.

Comment: @ecg8 Seems that you didn't read the entire question... I attached the JSFiddle link to my code and the images were just reference to ... Next time please have a good look at the code before downvoting.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that indeed solved the problem, thanks a lot. However it is still not clear for me why does it work in Chrome and not in Firefox.

Comment: @Camilo Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code

Comment: @ecg8 Thanks for the explanation. I edited the question according to the rules.

Comment: @Camilo when you ask *"it is still not clear for me why does it work in Chrome and not in Firefox"* you're asking the wrong question, because **it is working** on my Firefox. There is some other problem here. Somehow, your Firefox/SO combo is selecting a div in that JSFiddle frame.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @GerardoFurtado, the problem might be that the selector is selecting a `<div>` element out of nowhere and can be corrected by using a `null` selector as:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("null")
```

A detailed answer can be found here:
[Selecting null: what is the reason behind 'selectAll(null)' in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147231/selecting-null-what-is-the-reason-behind-selectallnull-in-d3-js)

Answer (score 0):

good day.
Firefox has compatibility issues with d3. One time a circle element was not being displayed on firefox, although there were no problem with chrome and edge. My code was something like

```
element.append("circle").style("r",10)
```

When I changed to

```
element.append("circle").attr("r",10)
```

it could be rendered on Firefox.
You could try change style element to attr element.
Hope it works.