# Single horizontal stacked bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to create a horizontal single stacked bar to use as a parts-to-whole graphic. Kind of like a pie chart, but a bar. I've been able to create a normal vertical and stacked bar chart before, but I'm not running into the same problems and the rect elements are not displaying at all.

I've removed the y-axis since the labels will be through a legend or appended text.

This is the error I'm getting:

> d3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to
>   object
>       at slice ()
>       at Function.n.range (d3.min.js:2)
>       at draw (singlestackedsharebar.html:94)
>       at d3.min.js:2
>       at Object. (d3.min.js:2)
>       at k.call (d3.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.min.js:2)

I think the issue is happening when I create the stack and series. When I log the series, it seems the next arrays aren't adding from the previous ones as they should.

Here's the full code:

```
function draw(data) {

  // Turns all the strings in the csv into integer values.

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Total = +d.Total;
  });

  var width = document.getElementById('barchart').offsetWidth,
    height = document.getElementById('barchart').offsetHeight;

  var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 200,
    bottom: 140,
    left: 260
  };

  var svg = d3.select('#barchart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
    .append('g');

  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // Create x and y scale.

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, height])
    .padding(0.1);

  // Create domains.

  xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.Total;
  })]);

  // Create axes.

  var x_axis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('padding', 1)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
      .ticks(10, 's'));

  // Choose which columns to have as keys with slice method.

  var keys = data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type;
  });

  // Create stack of the data with keys.

  var stack = d3.stack([data])
    .keys(["Total"]);

  console.log(keys);

  // Create series of the data.

  var series = stack(data);

  console.log(series);

  // Create color scale with colorbrewer or pass in array of colors.

  var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([0, 12])
    .range(colorbrewer.Oranges[12]);

  // Append rectangles.

  var bars = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(series)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.key);
    })
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) {
      return data.d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr('width', function(d, i) {
      return xScale(d[1]) - xScale(d[0]);
    });

};

<body>
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieterholger/dieterholger.github.io/master/data/disputeshare.csv', draw);
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of problems here. First the minor ones:

1. Rectangles must have `y` and `height` properties;
2. You are selecting existing elements in the enter selection (instead of that, use a [selectAll(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908));
3. Your x scale is using the maximum total as the top domain value. Instead of that, it should be the sum.

But, by far, the most important issue here is the stack generator. You simply cannot use the stack generator with the data you have, which is...

```
[
    {2015: "1528", 2016: "1187", Type: "Disputed Settlement Criteria/Bet Instructions", Total: 2715},
    {2015: "999", 2016: "676", Type: "Price Dispute", Total: 1675},
    {2015: "571", 2016: "299", Type: "Late Bets", Total: 870}
    //etc...
];
```

...for creating a single bar. On top of that, your `keys` method is wrong.

What you should do is creating an array **with a single object** on it:

```
var newData = [{}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
    newData[0][d.Type] = d.Total
});
```

And using your stack generator with this new array.

Here is the demo using your code as base and applying all the changes I mentioned. Also, I changed the height and width of the SVG for the demo:

```js
function draw(data) {

  // Turns all the strings in the csv into integer values.

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Total = +d.Total;
  });

  var width = 500,
    height = 100;

  var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 10
  };

  var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
    .append('g');

  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // Create x and y scale.

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, height])
    .padding(0.1);

  // Create domains.

  xScale.domain([0, d3.sum(data, function(d) {
    return d.Total;
  })]);

  // Create axes.

  var x_axis = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('padding', 1)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
      .ticks(10, 's'));

  // Choose which columns to have as keys with slice method.

  var keys = data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type;
  });

  var newData = [{}];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    newData[0][d.Type] = d.Total
  });

  // Create stack of the data with keys.

  var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(keys);

  // Create series of the data.

  var series = stack(newData);


  // Create color scale with colorbrewer or pass in array of colors.

  var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([0, 12])
    .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

  // Append rectangles.

  var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(series)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.key);
    })
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr('width', function(d, i) {
      return xScale(d[1]) - xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth());

};

d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieterholger/dieterholger.github.io/master/data/disputeshare.csv', draw);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```