# How to extend number of options in select tag using d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Consider a `select` html tag with only one option that I am using as title or placeholder.

I am using d3.js to render html view and add new elements or options to this tag based on data. This will change a lot, according to different datasets. That's why I am using this method.

However, this method does not return first option or first element in data, as you can see in snippet example. I have three main keys in this example: `a`, `b`, and `c`. And it just added two of them.

If I remove the first option in html view, it works ok. So, what is the best way to extend new options to select tag?

In order to add new, I used this code:

```
Object.keys(data).map((k) => {
  if (k == 'a') {
    options.push(k)
    options.push(k)
  } else {
    options.push(k)
  }
})
```

However, this would mean knowing what the first element is, and this is not true in most cases.

How can I achieve this result?

```js
var data = {
  'a': {
    'aa': 'aa'
  },
  'b': {
    'bb': 'bb'
  },
  'c': {
    'cc': 'cc'
  }
}

var options = []
Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
  options.push(k)
})

var selector = d3.select('#myid')
var opts = selector.selectAll('option')
    .data(options.sort())
    .enter()
    .append('option')
    .attr('value', function (d) {
      return d
    })
    .text(function (d) {
      return d
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<select id='myid' name='name' class='form-control'>
  <option disabled selected>Select one item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead selectAll `option` pass `null`.

```
var opts = selector.selectAll(null)
```

```js
var data = {
  'a': {
    'aa': 'aa'
  },
  'b': {
    'bb': 'bb'
  },
  'c': {
    'cc': 'cc'
  }
}

var options = []
Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
  options.push(k)
})

var selector = d3.select('#myid')
var opts = selector.selectAll(null)
    .data(options.sort())
    .enter()
    .append('option')
    .attr('value', function (d) {
      return d
    })
    .text(function (d) {
      return d
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<select id='myid' name='name' class='form-control'>
  <option disabled selected>Select one item</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good on you for using `selectAll(null)`.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: this answer has been edited and corrected based on [@GerardoFurtado's in depth explanation of this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46147232/9297144).*

---

When using `selectAll("option").data(data)`, as all `option` elements are selected, the one which is already present in the page (the one hardcoded in the html (`<option disabled selected>Select one item</option>`)) is also selected.

Thus, when `.enter()`ing this selection, the first data point considered is bound to this option which already exists in the page, thus skipping inserting the first option from the data.

For the remaining 2 data points to append, as we reached the limit of already existing `option` elements, then only, new `option` elements are created.

---

In this context the most appropriate response would be to use `.selectAll(null)` as [answered by @estebanpdl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50517643/9297144).

Here is another way to handle this use case (in order to demonstrate the impact of inserting new elements of a certain type when elements of this type already exist in the page). We can select and insert new data `option`s with a specific class to avoid taking into account the existing ones:

```
var opts = selector.selectAll('option .values')
  .data(options.sort())
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .attr("class", "values")
  .attr('value', function (d) { return d; })
  .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

---

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = {
  'a': { 'aa': 'aa' },
  'b': { 'bb': 'bb' },
  'c': { 'cc': 'cc' }
}

var options = [];
Object.keys(data).map(function (k) { options.push(k) });

var selector = d3.select('#myid');

var opts = selector.selectAll('option .values')
  .data(options.sort())
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .attr("class", "values")
  .attr('value', function (d) { return d; })
  .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<select id='myid' name='name' class='form-control'>
  <option disabled selected>Select one item</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not a *"weird"* behaviour at all! This is the very expected behaviour, well documented and explained by Bostock himself. For a better explanation of the internals, please have a look at this Q/A pair of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Comment: That clarifies a lot of things. I was at a loss to understand why the first element was skipped instead of the last one.