# D3JS graph donuts not showing some wedges when 2 donuts plotted

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We are displaying donut pie chart using d3js in asp.net. We are using d3.json for passing json data to display wheel level1. Wheel level1 is display as per the data. We are using another d3.json for passing json data to display wheel level2. But starting wedges of wheel level2 are not display in pie chart.

I observed that if I plot the DoNut of Level1 and Level2 independently it shows all wedges of both Level 1, Level2 respectively. 
When I changed the inner , out radius of Level1 and Level2 and displayed Level2 donut outside wiht Level1 donut inside, getting same problem of  some wedges not displayed.
The data of angles is stored in MySQL database, using the same the graph is plotted. I checked the sum of angles of all wedges for the Level 2 is 360.

here is the graph[image]

Sample code that is being used to plot Level1 DoNut

```
 d3.json("http://localhost:50025/SportsWheelServices.asmx/WheelLevel1", function (error, data) {

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.SectionId = d.SectionId;
            d.SectionLevel1 = d.SectionLevel1;
            d.GroupName = d.GroupName;
            d.SectionUpColor = d.SectionUpColor;
            d.Rotation = d.Rotation;
      });

        var label = d3.arc()
          .outerRadius(radius - 20)
          .innerRadius(400);

        var pie = d3.pie()
                       .sort(null)
                       .value(function (d) { return d.SectionLevel1; });

        var arc = d3.arc()         
           .outerRadius(radius - 20)
           .innerRadius(400);        

        var arcs = g.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)       
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return colors(data[i].SectionUpColor); });

        arcs.append("text")
         .attr("transform", function (d) {          
             var rotation = d.endAngle < Math.PI ? (d.startAngle / 2 + d.endAngle / 2) * 180 / Math.PI : (d.startAngle / 2 + d.endAngle / 2 + Math.PI) * 180 / Math.PI;
             return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ") rotate("+ d.data.Rotation+") rotate(" + rotation + ")";
         })         
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .text(function (d) { return d.data.GroupName; });

});
```

**Code for Level2 DoNut**

```
d3.json("http://localhost:50025/SportsWheelServices.asmx/WheelLevel2", function (error, data) {

        data.forEach(function(d)
        {
            d.SectionId = d.SectionId;
            d.SectionLevel2 = d.SectionLevel2;          
        });


        var label = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 20)
        .innerRadius(300);

        var pie = d3.pie()
                       .sort(null)            
                       .value(function (d) { return d.SectionLevel2; });

        var arc = d3.arc()
           .outerRadius(radius - 20)
           .innerRadius(300);

        var arcs = g.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc");

        arcs.append("path")            
           .attr("d", arc)
             .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return colors(i); });        
    });
```

Comment: In both charts, instead of `var arcs = g.selectAll(".arc")`, do `var arcs = g.selectAll(null)`. If you plan having an update selection, just set/use **different** class names. To read more about selecting `null` have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Comment: @GerardoFurtado , changed code    var arcs = g.selectAll(null)
   added null in selecAll(). But DoNut is not displayed.

   var arcs = g.selectAll(".arc")
……….
    Var arcs = g.selectAll(".arcs")
    We changed class name. But both donuts are displayed.

Comment: Did you change both `arcs` selections?

Answer (score 0):

instead of  var arcs = g.selectAll(".arc") I added the following code var arcs = g.selectAll(".arc" + index) this solved my problem