# How to guarantee old data is in d3's exit selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

#### Problem:

I'm trying to understand the behavior of d3's exit selection from the [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

**Note: I'm using d3V5**

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0fhno3u/19/)

Say I want to visualize the number "1".

```
var data = [{id:"1"}];
var text = svg.selectAll('.text').data(data);

text.enter()
    .each((d) => console.log("first append " + d))
    .append('text')
    .text(d => d.id)
```

All well and good. But now say I'm tired of "1" and more interested in visualizing "2".

```
data = [{id:"2"}];
text = svg.selectAll('.text').data(data);

text.exit().each((d) => console.log("remove " + d)).remove();
```

The console does not log `{id:"1"}`. This item was not placed in the exit selection.

```
text.enter()
    .each((d) => console.log("now append " + d))
    .append('text')
    .text(d => d.id)
```

Now I have a "1" and a "2" stacked right on top of one another.

#### Assumptions:

I had thought that when I do `.data(data)` d3 would do a diff between the dom and the data, and place any old dom nodes without corresponding entries in `data` in the exit selection. I had thought the `'id'` field on the data would distinguish these data elements. That doesn't seem to be the case.

#### Question:

How do I get `{id:"1"}` in the exit selection?

Or how do I remove the dom node associated with `{id:"1"}`?

Comment: You're just missing the key function inside the `data` method, that's all. This is certainly a duplicate, I'll find the target soon.

Comment: Oh. I had assumed the `'id'` property was used as the key by default in d3. I still haven't been able to fix my fiddle with a key function yet though... maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado still can't get the key function to work on the fiddle. Want to have a try?

Comment: Did you try `data(data, d => d.id)`? If you don't use a key function, the default is to use the index in the array (which for both your examples is `0`)

Comment: @AlexLenail Sorry, I was at my mobile previously, now I'm on my computer, easier to read the code. The issue here is not the lack of a key function (but it's always interesting having one), the problem here is that you're selecting a class that doesn't exist (`.text`). In effect, you were just selecting nothing (read my [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908)). Here is the same code selecting by tag: http://jsfiddle.net/hbzgoeu8/

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado! In my actual code, the solution turned out to be writing a key function and giving each element an ID so that the key function works properly. In my fiddle, the solution once I'd added the key function was adding the 'text' class -- forgetting to do that confused me. Feel free to mark this question as a duplicate of a key function question, or leave an answer if you would like. If I don't hear from you, I'll leave an answer on this question for future comers.

Comment: You can write the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here began with an erroneous assumption. In most of the d3 examples I've seen, the data has the following format:

```
[ {'id': 1, 'info': 'something'}, {'id': 2, 'info': 'something else'}, ...]
```

**I had been assuming that *selection*.data() performed a diff using the data's `'id'` field by default.**

It turns out that this isn't the case, and you need to offer your own key function.

From [D3's selection docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data):

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on.

So I added a key function:

```
function idFunc(d) { return d ? d.id : this.id; }

var data = [{id:"1"}];
var text = svg.selectAll('text').data(data, idFunc);

text.enter()
    .append('text')
    .text(d => d.id)
```

Then, dom nodes no longer corresponding to items in the data array found their way into the exit selection, and I was able to remove them.

#### Conclusions:

- (Always) Define a key function over your data when you `.data(data, keyFunc)`

Comment: Your second point in the conclusion is completely incorrect, I'm afraid. This has nothing to do with the issue you had: you don't need to set the `id` attribute or any other attribute. As I explained in my comment, the problem you had was simply a selection problem (you were selecting something that didn't exist).

Comment: In that case, what is the reason for the recommended ternary in `idFunc(d) { return d ? d.id : this.id; }`? When does it go to the second branch, and what is `this` ?

Comment: `.data(data, function(d) { return d ? d.name : this.id; })` from 
https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data

Comment: That's just to check the existence of the datum. And what has this to do with my comment? You don't need to set any `id` attribute in the element, the exit/enter selections work solely based on the **datum**. That's very clear: http://jsfiddle.net/ku4e1Lbx/

Comment: That being said, I have a strong feeling that you wrote an answer for your real code, not for the question you posted here. In your real code you probably already have DOM elements in the page, and that's why you need a ternary with the fallback for the lack of datum, with the elements having an ID. In your question here, however, you have no previously existing DOM elements, everything is created by enter selections. Therefore, you **don't need** to set an ID. Again, I suggest that you change the answer, or delete the whole Q/A pair, because your answer is simply wrong and misleading.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I don't have previously existing dom nodes on my page which weren't added by a selection.enter. I just tried removing all my `.attr("id", d => d.id)` and it seems my app still works, so I think you're correct that my answer here is wrong and misleading (thought not problematically misleading, I think, since setting an `.attr('id'` on elements isn't harmful). This situation confuses me more, though: what is `this` in the `idFunc` then?

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove mentions of the `.attr('id'`. Does the answer look better to you now?