# Appending text to rows and columns

Tags: d3.js

I have some very simple code that creates a 6x6 similarity matrix. And whilst i'm happy with the outcome, i'd like to append text (var teams) to each row of the grid. I've seen some good tutorials on SO (and elsewhere for that matter) for appending text to various elements on a graph, but haven't been able to locate anything related to visualisations with rows and columns. I'm just looking for a push in the right direction of how to proceed with this.

Cheers

```
var data = [ 
  [["Arsenal", 0.0], ["Chelsea", 0.6014876082652767], ["Liverpool", 0.5204181171517794],["ManchesterCity", 0.549210189254557], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5440890632512689], ["Tottenham", 0.6304670189118691]],
  [["Arsenal",0.6014876082652767], ["Chelsea",0.0], ["Liverpool",0.5507313736526684],["ManchesterCity",0.5559069243804156], ["MancheserUnited",0.5231358671618266], ["Tottenham",0.6508134781353688]],
  [["Arsenal",0.5204181171517794], ["Chelsea",0.5507313736526684], ["Liverpool",0.0],["ManchesterCity",0.49759390310994533], ["MancheserUnited",0.4787550034617063], ["Tottenham",0.5749363562907429]],
  [["Arsenal",0.549210189254557], ["Chelsea",0.5559069243804156], ["Liverpool",0.49759390310994533],["ManchesterCity",0.0,], ["MancheserUnited",0.50215325905151], ["Tottenham",0.5802928689025063]],
  [["Arsenal",0.5440890632512689], ["Chelsea",0.5231358671618266], ["Liverpool",0.4787550034617063],["ManchesterCity",0.50215325905151], ["MancheserUnited",0.0], ["Tottenham",0.5497016431211542]],
  [["Arsenal",0.6304670189118691], ["Chelsea",0.6508134781353688], ["Liverpool",0.5749363562907429],["ManchesterCity",0.5802928689025063], ["MancheserUnited",0.5497016431211542], ["Tottenham",0.0]]
];

var teams = ["ARS", "CHE", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN", "TOT"]

var cols = data.length;
var rows = data.length;
var cellSize = 55;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600 )
    .attr("height", 500)

svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      return "translate(" + i * cellSize + ")"
    })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {return d;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d[1] == 0) {
            return "#2A363B";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.50) {
            return "#F8B195";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.55) {
            return "#F67280";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.59) {
            return "#C06C84";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.62) {
            return "#6C5B7B";
        } else if (d[1] >= 0.63) {
            return "#355C7D";
        }})
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return i * cellSize ;
    })
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("r", 55);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each inner array of your `data` matrix contains the correct data for the rows. You can use any inner matrix, for instance the first:

```
.data(data[0])
```

Then it's just using some magic numbers (which you should avoid...) to positioning the texts:

```
var labels = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data[0])
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 440)
    .attr("y", function(_,i){
        return cellSize/2 + i * cellSize
    })
    .text(function(d){
        return d[0]
    });
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.0],
    ["Chelsea", 0.6014876082652767],
    ["Liverpool", 0.5204181171517794],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.549210189254557],
    ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5440890632512689],
    ["Tottenham", 0.6304670189118691]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.6014876082652767],
    ["Chelsea", 0.0],
    ["Liverpool", 0.5507313736526684],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.5559069243804156],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.5231358671618266],
    ["Tottenham", 0.6508134781353688]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.5204181171517794],
    ["Chelsea", 0.5507313736526684],
    ["Liverpool", 0.0],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.49759390310994533],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.4787550034617063],
    ["Tottenham", 0.5749363562907429]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.549210189254557],
    ["Chelsea", 0.5559069243804156],
    ["Liverpool", 0.49759390310994533],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.0, ],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.50215325905151],
    ["Tottenham", 0.5802928689025063]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.5440890632512689],
    ["Chelsea", 0.5231358671618266],
    ["Liverpool", 0.4787550034617063],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.50215325905151],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.0],
    ["Tottenham", 0.5497016431211542]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.6304670189118691],
    ["Chelsea", 0.6508134781353688],
    ["Liverpool", 0.5749363562907429],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.5802928689025063],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.5497016431211542],
    ["Tottenham", 0.0]
  ]
];

var teams = ["ARS", "CHE", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN", "TOT"]

var cols = data.length;
var rows = data.length;
var cellSize = 55;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 500)

svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * cellSize + ")"
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    if (d[1] == 0) {
      return "#2A363B";
    } else if (d[1] <= 0.50) {
      return "#F8B195";
    } else if (d[1] <= 0.55) {
      return "#F67280";
    } else if (d[1] <= 0.59) {
      return "#C06C84";
    } else if (d[1] <= 0.62) {
      return "#6C5B7B";
    } else if (d[1] >= 0.63) {
      return "#355C7D";
    }
  })
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * cellSize;
  })
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50);

var labels = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data[0])
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 440)
  .attr("y", function(_, i) {
    return cellSize / 2 + i * cellSize
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d[0]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is is the var labels = svg.selectAll(null) set to null?

Comment: You can read about it in my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908