# Missing first value while creating a bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've collected data of different questionnaires and now i'm going to visualize it for detail inspection by using d3. The problem is when I use bar graph to visualize percentage value of specific data, graph is drawn correctly but when i try to write values of specific entity to bar itself, first bar value doesn't print on bar itself. I couldn't understand where am doing wrong. Please help. here is my code

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data
d3.csv("Data_vis.csv", function(error, data) {


  var data=[{"salesperson":'Male', "sales": 55},
            {"salesperson":'Female', "sales": 38.75},
            {"salesperson":'White', "sales": 30.63},   
            {"salesperson":'Latino', "sales": 15.50},
            {"salesperson":'Black', "sales": 22.88},
            {"salesperson":'Native', "sales": 1.85},
            {"salesperson":'Asian', "sales": 13.28}];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    //alert(d.sales);
    d.sales = +d.sales;

  });


  svg.append("text")
       .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
       .attr("x", 50)
       .attr("y", 50)
       .attr("font-size", "24px")
       .text(heading)

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.salesperson; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sales; })]);


  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.salesperson); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.sales); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.sales); });


  svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
 .text(function(d) {

 var sal=d.sales;
 sal = sal.toFixed(2);
        return sal;
   })
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (width / data.length) + 5;  // +5
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        //alert(d);
        return height - (d.sales * 4) + 15;              // +15
   }); 




  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

[image]

any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Not related to the question, but here is a tip regarding data visualisation: don't mix categorical variables that belong to different groups, like `male, female` with `white, latino, black...`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. actually these categories are required by an educational institution for their visualization so i had to put them together. anyways thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
   .attr("x", 50)
   .attr("y", 50)
   .attr("font-size", "24px")
   .text(heading)
```

You are appending a `<text>` element to the SVG (and the `svg` selection). So far, so good.

Now comes this:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    //etc...
```

And this is what's happening: as you are selecting all `<text>` elements, you are in fact selecting that first one we mentioned, and binding data to it. Because of that, your enter selection has `n - 1` elements.

For a better explanation, please see my explanation here: [Selecting null: what is the reason behind 'selectAll(null)' in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908)

**Solution**: Select nothing...

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    //etc...
```

... or, if you plan to have an update selection, select by a given class.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot :)