# How to project several scatter plots over a background element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a shape--created with D3's area generator--with four distinct regions. And I have a function: *draw_graph(region, data)* which takes as input a region of the shape and a data set. The function encloses the region with a rectangle and populates a scatter plot inside the rectangle, from the data set.

My problem is that draw_graph only populates the graph the first two times it's invoked. It properly produces an x and a y axis and the enclosing rectangle on every invocation. But it only populates the fist two graphs. The order of the regions doesn't matter. Only the order in which the function is invoked

Draw_graph was previously only populating the first graph it drew. Then I switched from using randomly generated arrays as data to using hard coded arrays. With the hard-coded arrays the function started populating the first two graphs. Then I switched back to using randomly generated arrays and the behavior did not revert.

here is a link to my code. The draw_graph function starts at line 99:

https://bl.ocks.org/AveryBurke/f064b315faaa1842bc8bb2e3a45a1431/ac217f4d6b61a5b4ad3df0394017e4f394b0fe2e

And here is a running snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.9.1/dist/d3.min.js"></script> 
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    
 //add svg
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)
    .attr('stoke', 'red');
  
    
    
    //////////////GENERATEs AREA/////////////

// //Append a defs
var defs = svg.append("defs");
    
    

//Append a linearGradient element to the defs and give it a unique id
var linearGradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "linear-gradient");
    
//Horizontal gradient
linearGradient
    .attr("x1", "10%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "90%")
    .attr("y2", "0%");
        
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#eff3ff"); 
    
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "25%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#bdd7e7"); 
    
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "50%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#6baed6"); 
    
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "75%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#3182bd");

linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#08519c")
  .attr("stop-opacity", .8);
    

 var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, 8])
   .range([0, +innerWidth])
 var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0,4])
   .range([(3/4) * innerHeight, 50])
 
//generate area points
 var areaX = [... Array(9).keys()].map(xScale)
 var areaY1 = [.75, .74, 1.25, 1.24, 1.75, 1.74, 2, 2.31, 2.39].map(e => e * (innerHeight/9))
 var areaY0 = areaY1.map(e => innerHeight - e)
 
 //zip points into an array of arrays. areaPoints = [[areaX, areaY1, areaY0]...]
var zip = (...rows) => [...rows[0]].map((_,c) => rows.map(row => row[c]));
var areaPoints = zip(areaX, areaY1, areaY0); 
    
//creat and array of objects from the areaPoints array of arrays.
var points = []
areaPoints.forEach(a => points.push({x:a[0], heigh:a[1], low:a[2]}))

//areaGenerator
 var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(d => +d.x)
   .y0(d => +d.low)
   .y1(d => +d.heigh)
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
    
//render the area from the points array of objects
 var area = areaGenerator(points);
  
 d3.select('svg')
 .append('path')
 .attr('d', area)
 .attr('fill', "url(#linear-gradient)");



    
function draw_graph(region, data){ 
 var yTrans = points[region]['heigh'] - points[0]['heigh']
  var width = points[2]['x']
  var height = points[region]['low'] - points[region]['heigh']
  var xAxisTrans = yTrans + height + 40
  
//   the rectangle
  var rect = svg.append('rect')
        .attr('x', points[0]['x'])
        .attr('y', points[0]['heigh'])
        .attr('height',height)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${yTrans})`)//<-- translate the 
  
  //graph domain
  var dom = data
  
  
  // x and y scales
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(dom))
   .range([0, width])
  
  var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
   .domain(dom)
   .range([0, height])
  
 // x and Y axis 
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    
//  x and y Axis Groups
    var xAxisG = svg.append('g')
     .call(xAxis)
     .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${xAxisTrans})`)

    var yAxisG = svg.append('g')
     .call(yAxis)
     .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${points[region]['heigh']})`)
    
 //render data as points
    svg.selectAll('circle').data(dom).enter()
    .append('circle')
   .attr('cx', d => xScale(d))
   .attr('cy', d => yScale(d) + 40)
   .attr('r', 5)
   .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${yTrans})`)//<--translate points into rectangle
  
    }
    
  //Draw 4 graphs from 4 random arrays 
const com = [...Array(10)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
const vom = [...Array(50)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
const zom = [...Array(20)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
const jom = [...Array(20)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
draw_graph(0, com)//<--draw over the 1st region
draw_graph(4, vom)//<--draw over the 3rd region
draw_graph(2, zom)//<--draw over the 2nd region
draw_graph(6, jom)//<--draw over the 4th region 

  </script>
</body>
```

My plan is to invoke draw_graph four times (one for each region the background shape) with four individual data sets. The desired effect is that each region of the background shape will have its own scatter plot. At the moment my data sets are randomly generated arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're selecting all the circles and binding the data to them:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dom)
    .enter()
    //etc...
```

This can be easily fixed by selecting `null`:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(dom)
    .enter()
    //etc...
```

Here is your code with that change only:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.9.1/dist/d3.min.js"></script> 
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    
 //add svg
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)
    .attr('stoke', 'red');
  
    
    
    //////////////GENERATEs AREA/////////////

// //Append a defs
var defs = svg.append("defs");
    
    

//Append a linearGradient element to the defs and give it a unique id
var linearGradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "linear-gradient");
    
//Horizontal gradient
linearGradient
    .attr("x1", "10%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "90%")
    .attr("y2", "0%");
        
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#eff3ff"); 
    
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "25%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#bdd7e7"); 
    
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "50%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#6baed6"); 
    
linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "75%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#3182bd");

linearGradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#08519c")
  .attr("stop-opacity", .8);
    

 var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, 8])
   .range([0, +innerWidth])
 var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0,4])
   .range([(3/4) * innerHeight, 50])
 
//generate area points
 var areaX = [... Array(9).keys()].map(xScale)
 var areaY1 = [.75, .74, 1.25, 1.24, 1.75, 1.74, 2, 2.31, 2.39].map(e => e * (innerHeight/9))
 var areaY0 = areaY1.map(e => innerHeight - e)
 
 //zip points into an array of arrays. areaPoints = [[areaX, areaY1, areaY0]...]
var zip = (...rows) => [...rows[0]].map((_,c) => rows.map(row => row[c]));
var areaPoints = zip(areaX, areaY1, areaY0); 
    
//creat and array of objects from the areaPoints array of arrays.
var points = []
areaPoints.forEach(a => points.push({x:a[0], heigh:a[1], low:a[2]}))

//areaGenerator
 var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(d => +d.x)
   .y0(d => +d.low)
   .y1(d => +d.heigh)
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
    
//render the area from the points array of objects
 var area = areaGenerator(points);
  
 d3.select('svg')
 .append('path')
 .attr('d', area)
 .attr('fill', "url(#linear-gradient)");



    
function draw_graph(region, data){ 
 var yTrans = points[region]['heigh'] - points[0]['heigh']
  var width = points[2]['x']
  var height = points[region]['low'] - points[region]['heigh']
  var xAxisTrans = yTrans + height + 40
  
//   the rectangle
  var rect = svg.append('rect')
        .attr('x', points[0]['x'])
        .attr('y', points[0]['heigh'])
        .attr('height',height)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${yTrans})`)//<-- translate the 
  
  //graph domain
  var dom = data
  
  
  // x and y scales
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(dom))
   .range([0, width])
  
  var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
   .domain(dom)
   .range([0, height])
  
 // x and Y axis 
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    
//  x and y Axis Groups
    var xAxisG = svg.append('g')
     .call(xAxis)
     .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${xAxisTrans})`)

    var yAxisG = svg.append('g')
     .call(yAxis)
     .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${points[region]['heigh']})`)
    
 //render data as points
    svg.selectAll(null).data(dom).enter()
    .append('circle')
   .attr('cx', d => xScale(d))
   .attr('cy', d => yScale(d) + 40)
   .attr('r', 5)
   .attr("transform",
              `translate(${points[region]['x']},${yTrans})`)//<--translate points into rectangle
  
    }
    
  //Draw 4 graphs from 4 random arrays 
const com = [...Array(10)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
const vom = [...Array(50)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
const zom = [...Array(20)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
const jom = [...Array(20)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*40))
draw_graph(0, com)//<--draw over the 1st region
draw_graph(4, vom)//<--draw over the 3rd region
draw_graph(2, zom)//<--draw over the 2nd region
draw_graph(6, jom)//<--draw over the 4th region 

  </script>
</body>
```

To read more about `selection.selectAll(null)` have a look here: [Selecting null: what is the reason behind 'selectAll(null)' in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908). Also, pay attention to the last part, where I explain that, if you plant to have an update selection, you should not use `selection.selectAll(null)`. In that case, select the adequate circles accordingly.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! and more than that your explanation of selection.selectAll(null) has helped in my understanding of how D3 actually works. Thank so much