# Best way to use selection.filter to get multiple selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am just playing around with d3.js and I would like to know what's the best way to use `selection.filter()` or some other way to get multiple selections in a single loop.

Thinking from an array perspective, I would use `Array.prototype.filter()` to get the required set of data. Whenever I need multiple set of data based on different condition I would use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and push the data to respective key in the accumulator as object.

So with D3 selection how would I filter and and get the selection for different condition in a single loop.(something like `d3.reduce()`). So that I can use the selection methods over the filtered selections. I read the docs and I am aware that from v4 the selections are no more arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting: how to filter an selection and populate multiple selections **in a single** loop. However, I must to say that it's just as interesting as it is, probably, useless: the idiomatic way, which is quite simple, consists in just doing several filters:

```
const bigSelection = d3.selectAll(foo);

const smallSelection1 = bigSelection.filter(function with condition 1);
const smallSelection2 = bigSelection.filter(function with condition 2);
const smallSelection3 = bigSelection.filter(function with condition 3);
//etc...
```

However, just for the sake of curiosity: is this possible? Yes, it is. But using `selection.each`, not `selection.filter`.

My first idea was using `selection.merge`, but I had to quickly abandon it because, as Bostock (D3 creator) said,

> The current implementation of selection.merge only handles the case where the two selections have the same structure (i.e., the same parents and indexes), and returns a selection with the same structure.

So, I decided to just concatenate the nodes, which you can do with `Array.prototype.concat`. This is the idea: first, we declare some empty selections...

```
let foo = d3.selectAll(null);
let bar = d3.selectAll(null);
let baz = d3.selectAll(null);
```

Then, using an `each` in the bigger selection, we check for a property (here named `label`) and concat the nodes accordingly:

```
bigSelection.each(function(d) {
  if (d.label === "foo") {
    foo = d3.selectAll(foo.nodes().concat(this))
  } else if (d.label === "bar") {
    bar = d3.selectAll(bar.nodes().concat(this))
  } else {
    baz = d3.selectAll(baz.nodes().concat(this))
  }
});
```

Here is a demo. The big selection contains 10 circles, all of them black. Then, in the `each`, we populate three selections (`circlesFoo`, `circlesBar` and `circlesBaz`), which we paint in green, red and blue, respectively:

```js
const data = [{
    x: 20,
    label: "foo"
  },
  {
    x: 50,
    label: "bar"
  }, {
    x: 80,
    label: "foo"
  }, {
    x: 110,
    label: "baz"
  }, {
    x: 140,
    label: "bar"
  }, {
    x: 170,
    label: "baz"
  }, {
    x: 200,
    label: "baz"
  }, {
    x: 230,
    label: "foo"
  }, {
    x: 260,
    label: "foo"
  }, {
    x: 290,
    label: "bar"
  },
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 75)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", d => d.x);

let circlesFoo = d3.selectAll(null);
let circlesBar = d3.selectAll(null);
let circlesBaz = d3.selectAll(null);

circles.each(function(d) {
  if (d.label === "foo") {
    circlesFoo = d3.selectAll(circlesFoo.nodes().concat(this))
  } else if (d.label === "bar") {
    circlesBar = d3.selectAll(circlesBar.nodes().concat(this))
  } else {
    circlesBaz = d3.selectAll(circlesBaz.nodes().concat(this))
  }
});

circlesFoo.style("fill", "green");
circlesBar.style("fill", "red");
circlesBaz.style("fill", "blue");
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Null selection, which is something I didn't come up with. I didn't know it is possible. Good one. Let me try this

Comment: @DharanBro have a look at this Q/A pair I wrote about `selectAll(null)`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Comment: as you mentioned the idiomatic way, don't you think that it is unnecessary to run a filter again and again for different condition? When the bigSelection is huge then it impacts the performance. Why don't D3 doesn't want to handle this with an inbuilt api?

Comment: Because D3 programmers generally don't select everything and then filter sub-selections: we select according to the needs of each selection.

Comment: Funnily, this is about 50x **slower** than the idiomatic approach because of all the temporary selections created during the loop which are discarded on the next iteration: https://jsperf.com/d3-selection-multi-filter This can be circumvented, though, by first setting up arrays of nodes during filtering which are selected afterwards (see test case *".each() optimized"*). The optimized version performs twice as fast as the idiomatic solution. @DharanBro.

Comment: @DharanBro The above mentioned test results are for Chrome, using Firefox there is a tie between the idiomatic filter approach and the optimized each loop with the proposed solution still beaten by miles. The big takeway from this is that it's probably not worth it. If you want to optimize your code you have to be sure of what you are doing and really take care not to make things worse. And this applies to both performance **and** code style! It's always good to question styles and conventions but in this case I'd stick with the established best practices!

Comment: This is the kind of question that one answers just for the sake of the challenge, but one should add *"caveat lector, don't do this..."*.

Answer (score 0):

D3js has a filter function for its selections.

> **From [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter)**
>
> selection.filter(filter) <>
>
> Filters the selection, returning a new selection that contains only the elements for which the specified filter is true. The filter may be specified either as a selector string or a function. If the filter is a function, it is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]).

What this means is suppose you have a bunch of shapes (for example circles) which you intend on appending depending upon the data, you can utilize the filter function to specify a function which if it returns true it will append the circle for that point.

For example,

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.value < 100 }) //filters those data points below value of 100
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

If you would like to edit already existing objects just use the `filter` function after the selection i.e. `selectAll`:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.value < 20 }) //filters those data points below value of 20
  .attr("fill", "blue");
```

Unfortunately you do not have any code or specific example mentioned to guide you better.