# How can I add labels inside the points in a scatterplot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, scatter-plot

I am trying to add state abbreviations within a scatterplot like so:
[image: scatterplot with labels]

Here's a snippet of the CSV file I am working with:

```
id   abbr healthcare  poverty
 1   AL   13.9        19.3
 2   AK   15          11.2      
 3   AZ   14.4        18.2
 4   AR   16.3        18.9
 5   CA   14.8        16.4
 6   CO   12.8        12
 7   CT   8.7         10.8
 8   DE   8.7         12.5
```

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
// @TODO: YOUR CODE HERE!
var svgWidth = 750;
var svgHeight = 500;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 60, 
    left: 100
};

var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Create an SVG wrapper, append an SVG group that will hold our chart and shift the latter by left and top margins
var svg = d3.select("#scatter")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Import Data
d3.csv("data.csv").then(function(censusData) {

    // Parse Data & Cast as numbers
    censusData.forEach(function(data) {
        data.healthcare = +data.healthcare;
        data.poverty = +data.poverty;
    });

    // Create scale functions
    var xLinearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(censusData, d => d.poverty))
      .range([0, width]);

    var yLinearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(censusData, d => d.healthcare)])
      .range([height, 0]);

    // Create axis functions
    var bottomAxis = d3.axisBottom(xLinearScale);
    var leftAxis = d3.axisLeft(yLinearScale);

    // Append axes to the chart
    chartGroup.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(bottomAxis);

    chartGroup.append("g")
      .call(leftAxis);

    // Create circles
    var circlesGroup = chartGroup.selectAll("Circle")
      .data(censusData)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => xLinearScale(d.poverty))
      .attr("cy", d => yLinearScale(d.healthcare))
      .attr("r", "15")
      .attr("fill", "rgb(117, 145, 197)") 
      .attr("opacity", "0.5");

    // Add state labels to the points
    var circleLabels = circlesGroup.selectAll("text").data(censusData).enter().append("text");

    circleLabels
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.poverty; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.healthcare; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.abbr; })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "5px")
      .attr("fill", "white");

    // Create axes labels
    chartGroup.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left + 40)
      .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("class", "axisText")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Lacks Healthcare (%)");

    chartGroup.append("text")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height + margin.top + 30})`)
      .attr("class", "axisText")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("In Poverty (%)");

    // Initialize tooltip
    var toolTip = d3.tip() 
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .offset([80, -60])
      .html(function(d) {
        return  `${d.state}<br>Poverty: ${d.poverty}<br>Healthcare: ${d.healthcare}<br>`; 
    });

    // Create tooltip in the chart
    chartGroup.call(toolTip);

    // Create event listeners to display and hide the tooltip
    circlesGroup.on("mouseover", function(data) {
      toolTip.show(data, this);
    })
      // onmouseout event
      .on("mouseout", function(data, index) {
        toolTip.hide(data);
      });

});
```

I attempted to add them in the `circleLabels` part of the code but to no avail. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this part:

```
// Add state labels to the points
    var circleLabels = circlesGroup.selectAll("text").data(censusData).enter().append("text");

    circleLabels
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.poverty; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.healthcare; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.abbr; })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "5px")
      .attr("fill", "white");
```

Any suggestions or changes are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. `circlesGroup` is a circles' selection. You cannot append `<text>` elements to `<circle>` elements. Therefore, change it to `chartGroup`:

   ```
   var circleLabels = chartGroup.selectAll("text")//etc...
   ```

   and that brings us to the second problem:
2. There are text elements in that selection. So, to avoid binding data to existing elements (which reduces the size of the enter selection), use `selectAll(null`:

   ```
   var circleLabels = chartGroup.selectAll(null)//etc...
   ```

   to read more about `selectAll(null)`, read my Q/A pair here: [Selecting null: what is the reason behind 'selectAll(null)' in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908)
3. You are not using the scales for positioning the texts.

Finally, use `text-anchor: middle` for entering the texts.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var csv = `id,abbr,healthcare,poverty
1,AL,13.9,19.3
2,AK,15,11.2,
3,AZ,14.4,18.2
4,AR,16.3,18.9
5,CA,14.8,16.4
6,CO,12.8,12
7,CT,8.7,10.8
8,DE,8.7,12.5`;

const censusData = d3.csvParse(csv)

var svgWidth = 960;
var svgHeight = 500;

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 100
};

var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Create an SVG wrapper, append an SVG group that will hold our chart and shift the latter by left and top margins
var svg = d3.select("#scatter")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);


// Parse Data & Cast as numbers
censusData.forEach(function(data) {
  data.healthcare = +data.healthcare;
  data.poverty = +data.poverty;
});

// Create scale functions
var xLinearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(censusData, d => d.poverty))
  .range([0, width]);

var yLinearScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(censusData, d => d.healthcare)])
  .range([height, 0]);

// Create axis functions
var bottomAxis = d3.axisBottom(xLinearScale);
var leftAxis = d3.axisLeft(yLinearScale);

// Append axes to the chart
chartGroup.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(bottomAxis);

chartGroup.append("g")
  .call(leftAxis);

// Create circles
var circlesGroup = chartGroup.selectAll("Circle")
  .data(censusData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xLinearScale(d.poverty))
  .attr("cy", d => yLinearScale(d.healthcare))
  .attr("r", "15")
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("opacity", "0.5");

var circleLabels = chartGroup.selectAll(null).data(censusData).enter().append("text");

circleLabels
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xLinearScale(d.poverty);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yLinearScale(d.healthcare);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.abbr;
  })
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "10px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "white");

// Create axes labels
chartGroup.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left + 40)
  .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .attr("class", "axisText")
  .text("Lacks Healthcare (%)");

chartGroup.append("text")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height + margin.top + 30})`)
  .attr("class", "axisText")
  .text("In Poverty (%)");
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3Times</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/d3Style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <h1>D3Times</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-9">
        <div id="scatter">
          <!-- We append our chart here. -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer-->
  <div id="footer">
    <p>The Coding Boot Camp&copy;2016</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.9.1/d3-tip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```