# Text label hides in circle d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i've stuck for this code. Im trying to add text behind the circle
and sample code like this

> for the text:

```
        g.selectAll(".my-text")
            .data(marks)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "text-desc")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
                return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0]; 
            })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { 
               return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1]; 

            })
            .attr('dy', ".3em")
            .text(function() { return location})
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('color', 'white')
            .attr('font-size', 15)
```

> and for circle like this

```
             g.selectAll(".circle")
                .data(marktests)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "bubble")
                .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                     return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0]; 
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
                    return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1]; 
                })
                .attr("r", function() { 
                    return myRadius(locationGroup + 20);
                })
                .on('mouseover', tipBranch.show)
                .on('mouseout', tipBranch.hide)
                .on('click', function(d){
                    window.open('http://localhost:8000/detail/'+d.branch);
                });
           }
```

but i got result just like this

[image]

and the elements if using inspect element
[image]

Thank you if you can help to help me and explain how to solve the problem code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I noticed the following issue:

```
 g.selectAll(".my-text")
            .data(marks)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "text-desc")
```

Also the following line: `.text(function() { return location})` is faulty because you are missing the data object that you iterate with. This might be changed to: `.text(function(d) { return d.location})`

you are selecting all elements with class `.my-text` but then you are attaching `text-desc` as class to the text elements. The correct change for this would be:

```
 g.selectAll(".text-desc")
            .data(marks)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "text-desc")
```

considering that you want to use `text-desc` as a class. the same problem is with the circle as well: Either do: `g.selectAll("circle")` to select the circle tag elements or `g.selectAll(".bubble")` to select the bubbles.

You are also using different iterating objects for text and circles - usually you should iterate over a single collection.

Another issue with the sample is that `location` and `locationGroup` are not part of the collection items. I would expect that the values to be taken from the data object as such `.text( d => d.location)` and `.attr("r", d => myRadius(d.locationGroup))`. Before proceeding make sure that you populate iterating items with this properties.

Another approach would be to do the following:

```
const group = 
    g.selectAll('.mark')
     .data(marks)
     .enter()
     .append('g')
     .attr('class', 'mark')
     .attr('transform', d => {
        const proj = projection([d.long, d.lat])
        return `translate(${proj[0]}, ${proj[1]})`;
      })

group.append('text').text(d => return d.location) //apply other props to text
group.append('circle').text(d => return d.location) //apply other props to circle
```

Using this approach will allow you to iterate the collection with a group element and use translation property in order to move the group to the location (small improvement, projection will be executed once) and use the group to populate with other elements: text, circle.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you look at the element you'll see that there is a value (`4`) for those texts, so OP may indeed want to use `return location`, which returns a value... therefore, that is not the problem here (neither is the class name).

Comment: Makes sense but then the selectAll enter append won’t make sense

Comment: You don't need to select anything in the `selectAll`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908, and selecting a different class only breaks the "update" selection, not the "enter" selection. Anyway, those are not the problems OP is facing, even if they, for whatever reason, marked this as accepted (go figure it out...).