# For loop creating concentric donut charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used for-loops to create multiple charts from an array of arrays in the past, but this time around I'm getting stuck after the first iteration. Here is my snippet:

```js
var margins = {top:20, left:50, bottom:20, right:20};

var width = 300;
                var arcSize = (6 * width / 100);
                var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;

var extent = 1800;

                var data2 = [
                  [
                    {value: (231/extent*100), marker: 231, label: "Collective", color: '#b8cce4', neg:false},
                    {value: (233/extent*100), marker: 233, label: "Targeted", color: '#95b3d7', neg:false},
                    {value: (45/extent*100), marker: 45, label: "Specific", color: '#4f81b9', neg:false},
                  ],
                  [
                    {value: (231/extent*100), marker: 231, label: "Collective", color: '#b8cce4', neg:false},
                    {value: (233/extent*100), marker: 233, label: "Targeted", color: '#95b3d7', neg:false},
                    {value: (45/extent*100), marker: 45, label: "Specific", color: '#4f81b9', neg:false},
                  ],
                  [
                    {value: (231/extent*100), marker: 231, label: "Collective", color: '#b8cce4', neg:false},
                    {value: (233/extent*100), marker: 233, label: "Targeted", color: '#95b3d7', neg:false},
                    {value: (45/extent*100), marker: 45, label: "Specific", color: '#4f81b9', neg:false},
                  ]


                ];


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1100+100).attr('height', 1100+100);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

    for (var j=0; j <(data2.length); j++) {

      var data = data2[j];

      var arcs = data.map(function (obj, i) {
          return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - (width / 100) + innerRadius);
      });
      var arcsGrey = data.map(function (obj, i) {
          return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + ((arcSize / 2) - 2))).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - ((arcSize / 2)) + (innerRadius));
      });

var pieData = data.map(function (obj, i) {
    return [
        {value: obj.value * 0.75, arc: arcs[i], object: obj},
        {value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75, arc: arcsGrey[i], object: obj},
        {value: 100 * 0.25, arc: arcs[i], object: obj}];
});

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {
    return d.value;
});

var g = graphGroup.selectAll('g').data(pieData).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ',' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ') rotate(180)');
var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('g.textClass').data([{}]).enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('textClass', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ',' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ') rotate(180)');


g.selectAll('path').data(function (d) {
    return pie(d);
}).enter().append('path')
    .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            return "Text" + d.data.object.label
        }
    })
    .attr('d', function (d) {
        return d.data.arc(d);
    }).attr('fill', function (d, i) {
      if (d.data.object.neg==false) {
        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none' ;
      } else {
        return i == 0 ? 'red' : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none' ;
      }}).attr('class','segments');

/*
g.selectAll('.segments').attr('fill', function(d,i) {
  return d.data.object.neg==true ? 'red' : 'none';
});
*/

graphGroup.selectAll('g').each(function (d, index) {
    var el = d3.select(this);
    var path = el.selectAll('path').each(function (r, i) {
        if (i === 1) {
            var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({
                startAngle: r.startAngle + 0.05,
                endAngle: r.startAngle + 0.001 + 0.05
            });
            var lableObj = r.data.object;
            var thisLength = this.getTotalLength();
            g.append('text')
                .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
                .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
                /*.attr('transform', "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + (centroid[1] + 10) + ") rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * r.startAngle + 7) + ")")
                 .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')*/
                .append("textPath")
                .attr("textLength", function (d, i) {
                    return 0;
                })
                .attr("xlink:href", "#Text" + r.data.object.label)
                .attr("startOffset", function() {
  return index === 2 || index === 3 ? thisLength - 22 : 5
})
                .attr('font-weight','normal')
                .attr("dy", '-3em')
                .text(function(d) {
                  if (lableObj.neg==true) {
                    return '-'+lableObj.marker;
                  } else {
                    return lableObj.marker ;
                  }
                  });
        }
        if (i === 0) {
            var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
                startAngle: r.startAngle,
                endAngle: r.startAngle
            });
            var lableObj = r.data.object;
            gText.append('text')
                .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
                .text(lableObj.label)
                .attr('transform', "translate(" + (centroidText[0] - ((1.5 * width) / 100)) + "," + (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + (180) + ")"))
                .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central');
        }
    });
});


}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

I'm unable to determine why I do not have multiple charts. No errors are thrown. There should be a new chart positioned 300 pixels away from the previous one -- for a total of 3 (my parent array has 3 arrays in it)

Relevant code:

```
var g = graphGroup.selectAll('g').data(pieData).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ',' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ') rotate(180)');
var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('g.textClass').data([{}]).enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('textClass', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ',' + (width / 2+(j*300)) + ') rotate(180)');
```

### Question

Is assigning a dynamic `transform()` based on the current iteration of my for-loop the least painstaking way to create 3 separate charts on the page? If so, then what is my flaw?

**Note:** While I'm very keen to learn my wrong step in the above implementation, I'm not totally opposed to a separate work-around if answerers feel so inclined.

Comment: You had the wrong D3 version in your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for` loop to append elements in a D3 code is definitely **not** the idiomatic way. A very simple D3 approach would be just binding the data to a `<g>` enter selection for appending your three groups, and then appending the donuts in an inner selection (which inherits the data).

When you use a JS loop, be it a `for` loop, a `forEach`, a `while` etc., bugs and strange things can happen (actually they are not "strange" but quite expected given how D3 selections operate). In your case, it's here:

```
var g = graphGroup.selectAll("g");
```

When you do that, you're selecting pre-existing groups, and therefore your enter selection is empty.

A very quick solution is just:

```
var g = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
```

To read more about `selectAll(null)`, have a look here: [Selecting null: what is the reason behind 'selectAll(null)' in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908)

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  left: 50,
  bottom: 20,
  right: 20
};

var width = 300;
var arcSize = (6 * width / 100);
var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;

var extent = 1800;

var data2 = [
  [{
      value: (231 / extent * 100),
      marker: 231,
      label: "Collective",
      color: '#b8cce4',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (233 / extent * 100),
      marker: 233,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: '#95b3d7',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (45 / extent * 100),
      marker: 45,
      label: "Specific",
      color: '#4f81b9',
      neg: false
    },
  ],
  [{
      value: (231 / extent * 100),
      marker: 231,
      label: "Collective",
      color: '#b8cce4',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (233 / extent * 100),
      marker: 233,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: '#95b3d7',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (45 / extent * 100),
      marker: 45,
      label: "Specific",
      color: '#4f81b9',
      neg: false
    },
  ],
  [{
      value: (231 / extent * 100),
      marker: 231,
      label: "Collective",
      color: '#b8cce4',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (233 / extent * 100),
      marker: 233,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: '#95b3d7',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (45 / extent * 100),
      marker: 45,
      label: "Specific",
      color: '#4f81b9',
      neg: false
    },
  ]


];


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1100 + 100).attr('height', 1100 + 100);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

for (var j = 0; j < (data2.length); j++) {

  var data = data2[j];

  var arcs = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - (width / 100) + innerRadius);
  });
  var arcsGrey = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + ((arcSize / 2) - 2))).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - ((arcSize / 2)) + (innerRadius));
  });

  var pieData = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return [{
        value: obj.value * 0.75,
        arc: arcs[i],
        object: obj
      },
      {
        value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75,
        arc: arcsGrey[i],
        object: obj
      },
      {
        value: 100 * 0.25,
        arc: arcs[i],
        object: obj
      }
    ];
  });

  var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

  var g = graphGroup.selectAll(null).data(pieData).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ',' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ') rotate(180)');
  var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('g.textClass').data([{}]).enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('textClass', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ',' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ') rotate(180)');


  g.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
      return pie(d);
    }).enter().append('path')
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      if (i == 1) {
        return "Text" + d.data.object.label
      }
    })
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return d.data.arc(d);
    }).attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      if (d.data.object.neg == false) {
        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
      } else {
        return i == 0 ? 'red' : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
      }
    }).attr('class', 'segments');

  /*
  g.selectAll('.segments').attr('fill', function(d,i) {
    return d.data.object.neg==true ? 'red' : 'none';
  });
  */

  graphGroup.selectAll('g').each(function(d, index) {
    var el = d3.select(this);
    var path = el.selectAll('path').each(function(r, i) {
      if (i === 1) {
        var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({
          startAngle: r.startAngle + 0.05,
          endAngle: r.startAngle + 0.001 + 0.05
        });
        var lableObj = r.data.object;
        var thisLength = this.getTotalLength();
        g.append('text')
          .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
          .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
          /*.attr('transform', "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + (centroid[1] + 10) + ") rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * r.startAngle + 7) + ")")
           .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')*/
          .append("textPath")
          .attr("textLength", function(d, i) {
            return 0;
          })
          .attr("xlink:href", "#Text" + r.data.object.label)
          .attr("startOffset", function() {
            return index === 2 || index === 3 ? thisLength - 22 : 5
          })
          .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
          .attr("dy", '-3em')
          .text(function(d) {
            if (lableObj.neg == true) {
              return '-' + lableObj.marker;
            } else {
              return lableObj.marker;
            }
          });
      }
      if (i === 0) {
        var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
          startAngle: r.startAngle,
          endAngle: r.startAngle
        });
        var lableObj = r.data.object;
        gText.append('text')
          .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
          .text(lableObj.label)
          .attr('transform', "translate(" + (centroidText[0] - ((1.5 * width) / 100)) + "," + (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + (180) + ")"))
          .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central');
      }
    });
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```