# How to make this D3 horizontal bar chart work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Recently I have started learning D3.js v5 and I have to make different sorts of graph. One of those graphs is a stacked horizontal bar chart. I followed a tutorial in Udemy but I am not able to make this chart to work.

Can anybody help me out?

So, I know d3 uses a stack generator to generate stacked bar chart. I used it and checking the values in console it seems that the data is formatted pretty well and and can start generating stacked bar chart but i can't seem to understand why its not working.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<body></body>


<script type="text/javascript">
var Margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 110};
var InnerWidth = 432 - Margin.left - Margin.right;
var InnerHeight = 432 - Margin.top - Margin.bottom;
var diff_variant=[{Missense_Mutation: 5, Silent: 4, Splice_Site: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 8, Splice_Site: 0, Silent: 0},
      {Splice_Site: 4, Missense_Mutation: 4, Silent: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 4, Silent: 1, Splice_Site: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 5, Splice_Site: 0, Silent: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 5, Splice_Site: 0, Silent: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 4, Splice_Site: 0, Silent: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 4, Splice_Site: 0, Silent: 0},
      {Silent: 1, Missense_Mutation: 1, Splice_Site: 0},
      {Missense_Mutation: 1, Splice_Site: 0, Silent: 0}];

var data1=[{name: "Missense_Mutation", count: 41},
           {name: "Silent", count: 6},
           {name: "Splice_Site", count: 4}];

var variant_name=["Missense_Mutation", "Splice_Site", "Silent"];

var stack = d3.stack().keys(variant_name);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d){return d.count;})])
          .range([0,InnerWidth]);

var x_axis = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d){return d.count;})])
               .range([0,InnerWidth]);

var y_axis = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, data1.length])
               .range([0,InnerWidth]);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .domain(data1.map(function(d){return d.name;}))
          .rangeRound([0,InnerHeight])
          .padding(0.1);

var svg5 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
             .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
             .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${InnerWidth + Margin.left + Margin.right} ${InnerHeight + Margin.top + Margin.bottom}`)
             .style("background","lightblue")
             .append("g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + Margin.left + "," + Margin.top + ")");

          svg5.append("g").style("font", "12px sans").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
          svg5.append("g").attr('transform', `translate(0, ${InnerHeight})`).style("font", "12px times").call(d3.axisBottom(x_axis));


var series = svg5.selectAll("g").data(stack(diff_variant))
                        .enter().append("g")
                        .style("fill", (d,i)=>d3.schemeSet3[i]);

        series.selectAll("rect").data(function(d){return d;})
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("height", 25)
                .attr("width", function(d){return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);})
                .attr("x", function(d){return x(d[0]);})
                .attr("y", function(d,i){return i*40;});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this...

```
var series = svg5.selectAll("g")//etc...
```

... you are selecting `<g>` elements that already exist in the SVG (the two axes) and binding data to them. That's why your enter selection is empty.

You can select `null` (read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908)):

```
var series = svg5.selectAll(null)
```

Or you can select by a class, that you later set in the enter selection:

```
var series = svg5.selectAll(".foo")
```

However, the best solution is just moving the axes' group to the bottom: that not only will fix your issue, but it will also paint the axis above the rectangles.

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

  <body></body>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 110
    };
    var InnerWidth = 432 - Margin.left - Margin.right;
    var InnerHeight = 432 - Margin.top - Margin.bottom;
    var diff_variant = [{
        Missense_Mutation: 5,
        Silent: 4,
        Splice_Site: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 8,
        Splice_Site: 0,
        Silent: 0
      },
      {
        Splice_Site: 4,
        Missense_Mutation: 4,
        Silent: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 4,
        Silent: 1,
        Splice_Site: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 5,
        Splice_Site: 0,
        Silent: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 5,
        Splice_Site: 0,
        Silent: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 4,
        Splice_Site: 0,
        Silent: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 4,
        Splice_Site: 0,
        Silent: 0
      },
      {
        Silent: 1,
        Missense_Mutation: 1,
        Splice_Site: 0
      },
      {
        Missense_Mutation: 1,
        Splice_Site: 0,
        Silent: 0
      }
    ];

    var data1 = [{
        name: "Missense_Mutation",
        count: 41
      },
      {
        name: "Silent",
        count: 6
      },
      {
        name: "Splice_Site",
        count: 4
      }
    ];

    var variant_name = ["Missense_Mutation", "Splice_Site", "Silent"];

    var stack = d3.stack().keys(variant_name);

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) {
        return d.count;
      })])
      .range([0, InnerWidth]);

    var x_axis = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) {
        return d.count;
      })])
      .range([0, InnerWidth]);

    var y_axis = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, data1.length])
      .range([0, InnerWidth]);

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data1.map(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      }))
      .rangeRound([0, InnerHeight])
      .padding(0.1);

    var svg5 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${InnerWidth + Margin.left + Margin.right} ${InnerHeight + Margin.top + Margin.bottom}`)
      .style("background", "lightblue")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + Margin.left + "," + Margin.top + ")");

    var series = svg5.selectAll("g").data(stack(diff_variant))
      .enter().append("g")
      .style("fill", (d, i) => d3.schemeSet3[i]);

    series.selectAll("rect").data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("height", 25)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 40;
      });

    svg5.append("g").style("font", "12px sans").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    svg5.append("g").attr('transform', `translate(0, ${InnerHeight})`).style("font", "12px times").call(d3.axisBottom(x_axis));

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried moving the axes group below but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. The plot is still just showing just the axes and not the bars.

Comment: Please click "Run code snippet". It **clearly** fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry my fault... Yes, this fixes my problem thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you're not using the `y` scale, and there are other problems with your stacked data.

Comment: yeah, I'm supposed to get 3 bars but I'm getting 10 bars. How am I suppose to fix that?