# d3.js - empty selectAll() in enter() sequence has no effect?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the effect of the initial `selectAll(...)` in a standard `enter().append()` sequence when the selection is empty?  It seems only the `append` has any effect.  For example:

**index.html** (abridged)

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
var data = ["a", "b", "c"];

var vis = d3.select("#example");

vis.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

creates

```
<div id="example">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

Where does the "foo" go?  If we're doing an empty selection does it matter at all what we put in `selectAll`?

It might be nice, for example, to be able to do `selectAll(".foo").enter().append("p")` to class all the created `<p>`, instead of the required `...append("p").attr("class", "foo")`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't matter what goes into the `selectAll()` for an empty selection as long as the selector doesn't match any existing element (otherwise it wouldn't be an empty selection). As for why you can't make an empty selection with (".foo") to set the entered element's class, I can only guess how Mike feels: The selectAll() selector doesn't set the entered element's class or type if the selection is empty, because then the behavior would change depending on if the selection was empty or not (as you don't *always* want the selector to affect what is appended in a non-empty selection).

Comment: To explicitly make an empty selection, [selectAll(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/7106086) is a common approach.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid that makes sense for what it does and why it shouldn't be any other way.  And thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that post.