# A more elegant way to bind new elements using data bound to multiple group elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When working with d3.js I often encounter the situation where I would like to create some groups that contain specific parts of my data set. These groups are then used to bound some other elements to it after transforming the data contained by the groups with some function. I have been searching for an elegant situation for a while, but haven't found one yet. I now use the each function, but I reckon there must be a better way to do this. If anyone knows of a better way to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
d3.json("example.json").then(data => {
  d3.select("#A")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "A_SVG")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height",height);
  d3.select("#A_SVG")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
    .attr("id", "A_CHART");
  d3.select("#A_CHART")
    .selectAll(".stateProperty")
    .data(Object.entries(data["A"]))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "stateProperty")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(0,${i * rowSpacing})`);
 d3.select("#A_CHART")
    .selectAll(".stateProperty")
    .each(function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(getNotHoldsRectValues(d[1]))
        .enter()
        .append("rect");
    });
});

function getNotHoldsRectValues(data) {
return [data[0],data[1]]
}
```

example.json:

```
{
  "A": {
    "tick_update": [
      { "holds": 1535602060 },
      { "not_holds": 1535602070 },
      { "holds": 1535602120 },
      { "not_holds": 1535602130 }
    ],
    "some_property": []
  },
  "B": {
    "tick_update": [
      { "holds": 1535602060 },
      { "not_holds": 1535602070 },
      { "holds": 1535602120 },
      { "not_holds": 1535602130 },
      { "holds": 1535602180 },
      { "not_holds": 1535602610 }
    ],
    "some_property": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the *"elegant"* way is just the default, idiomatic way.

First, avoid selecting elements all the time. That's a slow process. Instead of that, **name your selections** and use them.

So, this...

```
d3.select("#A")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "A_SVG")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height",height);
d3.select("#A_SVG")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
    .attr("id", "A_CHART");
```

Becomes:

```
const svg = d3.select("#A")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "A_SVG")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height",height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
    .attr("id", "A_CHART");
```

That way, you just need to use your new const `svg` whenever you want to refer to that selection. That can be applied to all sub-selections.

Secondly, there is no need for an `each` here, simply call the enter selection in the group you want.

All that being said, this could be your code:

```
d3.json("example.json").then(data => {
  const svg = d3.select("#A")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "A_SVG")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
  const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
    .attr("id", "A_CHART");
  const myGroups = g.selectAll(null)
    .data(Object.entries(data["A"]))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "stateProperty")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(0,${i * rowSpacing})`);
  const rects = myGroups.selectAll(null)
    .data(getNotHoldsRectValues(d[1]))
    .enter()
    .append("rect");
});
```

Here I'm using [`selectAll(null)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908), assuming you don't have an update selection.

Finally, it's not clear to me why you are using `Object.entries()` and that `getNotHoldsRectValues` function. That might be worth a new question.

Comment: Thanks so much! First of all for clearing up the performance benefits of avoiding selections. With more elegant I indeed just meant, the right way. It is now clear to me where I went wrong and why the use of each is unnecessary. The Object.entries is in there because my json data for the "A" key is not in the form of an array of records and I require both the values and the keys later on. The getNotHoldsRectValues is just some function to transform the data into attributes required to draw rectangles for the state "notHolds" values.