# Adding text to D3js shape created (rectangle & triangle symbol)

Tags: d3.js

[image]

I'm not sure why i cannot use both code for adding text to triangle and rectangle together.

If i'm using both, only text for triangle will be displayed. Text for rectangle should displayed at yellow.

If i remove code for adding text to triangle, then only text for rectangle will be displayed.

**Below is my code for creating the shape and adding text.**

```
    let axes_width2: any = 900;
    let axes_height2: number = 150;
    let axes_svg2: any = d3select
            .selectAll('tr')
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", axes_width2)
            .attr("height", axes_height2);        
    // Create scale
    let scale: any = d3select.scaleTime()
            //.domain([d3select.min(data), d3select.max(data)])
            .domain([new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2021, 0, 1)])
            .range([40, axes_width - 30]); 
//golive date
    var myData = [new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 1)];      
          var testdata = [{ start: new Date(2020, 2, 0), close: new Date(2020, 9, 0) }];       
//draw rect2
        axes_svg2
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(testdata)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .style("fill", "#00a19c")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return scale(d.start);
            })
            .attr("y", 80) //distance from axis
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return (scale(d.close) - scale(d.start));
            })
            .attr("height", 20); //height

    //create symbol
        var symbol = d3select.symbol().size(150).type(d3select.symbolTriangle);


        //create triangle
        axes_svg2
            .selectAll('path')
            .data(myData)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('width', 50)
            .attr('height', 50)
            .style("fill", "#232496")

            //.attr('transform', 'translate(50, 50)')
            .attr('d', function () { return symbol(); })
            .attr('transform', function (d, i) { return "translate(" + (scale(d)) + "," + (60) + ")"; });

        //add text to triangle
        axes_svg2
            .selectAll('text')
            .data(myData)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return scale(d) + 10;
            })
            .attr("y", 60)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            //.attr("font-family","Museo Sans 300")
            .text("Go-Live");

        //add text to rectangle
        axes_svg2
            .selectAll('text')
            .data(testdata)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return scale(d.start);
            })
            .attr("y", 120)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            //.attr("font-family","Museo Sans 300")
            .text("Start Date");
```

Comment: You are re-selecting the previous texts and binding another dataset to them. Nothing will be appended. Try `selectAll(null)`, as I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for your response. Yes it help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make changes as below :

```
//add text to rectangle
        axes_svg2
            .selectAll('null')
            .data(testdata)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return scale(d.start);
            })
            .attr("y", 120)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            //.attr("font-family","Museo Sans 300")
            .text("Start Date");
```