# How can I draw circles for two different columns in d3 v5?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatterplot of my data which consists of three columns of Year, Men and Women. I want to draw circles for both Men and Women columns that correspond to the year. Here's the code I've written, but only the first set of circles are added to the SVG. I'm using d3 v5.

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.Year))
                .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.Men))
                .attr("r", d => aScale(d.Men))
                .attr("id", "men")
                .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round((d.Men) * 20) + ")"
                });

                svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.Year))
                .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.Women))
                .attr("r", d => aScale(d.Women))
                .attr("id", "women")
                .attr("fill", "green");
```

Comment: If you don't plan to update the chart, change all `svg.selectAll("circle")` to `svg.selectAll(null)`. For an explanation, have at my Q/A pair here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908. If you do plan to have an update, use a *specific* class to each group.

Comment: I don't want to update the chart. Thank you, your answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong the enter() method.
The enter evaluates witch data is newer, using the selector before. In your case, the selector is circle. Like you are using again the same selector, data and enter for the second case, the enter doesn't detect new changes. Your must to store the enter in a variable and use it for both:

```
const circleEnter = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter();

circleEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.Year))
            .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.Men))
            .attr("r", d => aScale(d.Men))
            .attr("id", "men")
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round((d.Men) * 20) + ")"
            });

circleEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.Year))
            .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.Women))
            .attr("r", d => aScale(d.Women))
            .attr("id", "women")
            .attr("fill", "green");
```

Good luck!