# d3.js missing first index when append circles

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to using D3 and running - again - in some trouble.
I'm working on a small network, in this case without forces. Now i have the problem, that when adding my circles(my nodes) he skip the first index, and i'm not sure how to solve this.

you can find my complete code here:
https://github.com/katjalennartz/ba

here, i still have all the data

```
    var circleGroup = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(users)
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            console.log(d) //index 0 ist still there
             return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));
```

and this is where it goes missing

```
        .attr("r", function (d) {
            //increase radius if current user
            //index 0 is missing ?
            if (d.id === thisuser) {  
                return radius * 2 
            }
            else { return radius; }
        })
        .attr("class", "chara")
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            //set color to red if this user
            let color
            (d.id === thisuser) ? color = "red" : color = "blue"
            return color;
        })
        .style("stroke", "#ffffff");
```

So, i have no idea, what to do about it and i'm hoping someone here can help me fix it.

if it's important for the code, i'm planning to use update etc. to filter the links.

Thank you!

Comment: When you do `var circleGroup = svg.selectAll('g')` you already have a `g` element in the SVG, which is `var link`. Because of that, the first data element is being bound to that existing group. There are different solutions, for instance `var circleGroup = svg.selectAll(null)`, as I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Comment: thanks a  lot. this was the problem :)