# How should I replace this .selectAll necessary before .data in D3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

What should I replace `.selectAll('xxx') with?

I found this code which in the end outputs an xy diagram through D3.
The `.whatever` does not look fullt thought through.
So I tried to remove it and got an error.
How/what should I replace it?/it with?
(no, there is no nothing called `.whatever` or `whatever` anywhere.)

```
const element = this.mainContainer
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'xyDots');
element
  .selectAll('.whatever') <-- If I remove this call I get an error.
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')...
```

Error if said row is removed: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"

Extra XP for answering What is the side effect that makes `.selectAll('.whatever')` work in this case?

Comment: `selectAll('.whatever')` has the same effect as `.selectAll(null)` if there are no corresponding elements, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46147232/7106086) answer might be useful, I know there's some potentially more specific answers.

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/cmgiven/32d4c53f19aea6e528faf10bfe4f3da9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that in your case what arguments you passed to `selectAll()` doesn't matter; however, you cannot remove the `selectAll` statement, even though the arguments specified in `selectAll()` does not exist.
The point for `selectAll` is part of d3's enter-update-exit pattern. [Here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) is an article from Mike Bostock for you to check out. 
In the code you provided, it appears that you are only trying to append elements, but I would still recommend you to change `selectAll('.whatever')` to `selectAll('circle')`. It would be good styling(less confusing, of course), and, it would help you avoid errors in case you decided to update the elements in the future.

Hope this helps!