# Null node in d3js Graph visualisation

Tags: d3.js

I'm a beginner in `d3.js` and I have a weird problem in creating the graph with `d3.v3`. I miss the node with `index 0`.

[image]

Here is the output of the `console.log(gnode)`:

```
[Array(4)]
0: Array(4)
0: null
1: g
2: g
3: g
parentNode: g
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And here is my code:

```
var svg_graph = svg.append('svg:g')
var vis = svg_graph.append("svg:g");
gnode = vis.selectAll("g").data(graph.nodes).enter().append("g")
node = gnode.append("circle")
       .attr("r", 8)
       .attr('fill', '#fc434b')
       .attr('id', 'node')
```

In case I write the code as following, the problem is solved, but I need to add `g` in order to add text to each node later.

```
gnode = vis.selectAll("circle").data(graph.nodes).enter().append("circle")
node = gnode.attr("r", 8)
       .attr('fill', '#fc434b')
       .attr('id', 'node')
```

Comment: Do this: `gnode = vis.selectAll(null).data(graph.nodes).enter().append("g")`. For a detailed explanation, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147231/selecting-null-what-is-the-reason-behind-selectallnull-in-d3

Comment: Amazing and thank you! It's solved.

Answer (score -1):

First, don't use **V3**, it's outdated. Use **V5** or higher.

The common case of the D3 enter/exit pattern is:

```
selectAll(...).data(items, item => item.id).enter()
```

, where the second argiment of **data()** specifies the way of identification for the rendered objects. So, your data should be like:

```
[
  {id: 1, ...},
  {id: 2, ...},
  ...
  {id: N, ...}
]
```

, where **id** attribute is *unique* in the scope of entered objects

Check your data (**graph.nodes**) to be valid.